# JOIN works on two tables individually, but not when used together

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-8.4

Edit: nevermind, figured it out, answer below if you're interested.

Using Postgresql 8.4.

Here's the format of the query I need to run (names and faces have been changed to protect my paranoia.  they can be provided if necessary, but this is a direct copy of my query with simple substitution for schema, table and column names):

```
SELECT
    t1.field,
    SUM(v3.quantity) as current_qty
FROM
    schema1.child_table t1
        JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t1key FROM schema2.child_transaction t2 WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-19') t2 USING (t1key)
        LEFT JOIN schema1.child_current_status v3 ON t1.t1key = v3.t1key
        JOIN schema1.parent_table t4 ON t1.t4key = t4.t4key
WHERE
    t4.criteria = 763
GROUP BY
    t1.field
```

... basically, I need the `field` from `child_table` when `criteria` matches my provided data in `parent_table`, and when there is at least one relevant transaction in `child_transaction` during the requested period.  If there are quantities in the `child_current_status` view, we want those as well.

`t1.field` can be considered a human readable equivalent to numeric key `t4.criteria`.

My problem is that the query as provided fails to provide quantity data from `child_current_status` even when there is data there.

*Edit: to clarify, the above query returns `field, NULL`, where it should return `field, current_qty`*

The problem is related to the `t2` subquery, because when I change that to a `LEFT JOIN`, it returns the relevant quantity data:

```
SELECT
    t1.field,
    SUM(v3.quantity) as current_qty
FROM
    schema1.child_table t1
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT t1key FROM schema2.child_transaction t2 WHERE datefield BETWEEN '2012-04-01' AND '2012-04-19') t2 USING (t1key)
        LEFT JOIN schema1.child_current_status v3 ON t1.t1key = v3.t1key
        JOIN schema1.parent_table t4 ON t1.t4key = t4.t4key
WHERE
    t4.criteria = 763
GROUP BY
    t1.field
```

*Edit: this modified query returns `field, current_qty`, but will do so whether there are transactions in `child_transaction` for the requested time period or not*

... all I've done is turn the first JOIN into a LEFT JOIN, and that query returns with the relevant quantities in `child_current_status`.  If I change the `child_current_status` to an INNER JOIN, the query returns nothing.  The problem with making the first JOIN a LEFT JOIN is that I need it to only return results when there is data returned from the sub query, which there is in this case for the requested time period.

To muddy the waters, it works properly for *some* `t4.criteria`, 763 is just one that it fails on.

What am I missing here?

---

Short version: From the first query above, when the first JOIN is an INNER JOIN, it causes the LEFT JOIN to return nothing.  When it's a LEFT JOIN, the LEFT JOIN on `child_current_status` returns the proper data, but that negates the purpose of the first JOIN.

*Edit: I've tried moving the LEFT JOIN to the end of the FROM clause, behind the INNER JOINs, with no change*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh, nevermind, I figured it out, the query is working properly and there's not enough data here for anyone else here to figure it out.  Basically, there is one transaction for one child in the `child_table`, and there are current quantities for other children in the `child_table`.  So the query appropriately indicates that there are no current quantities for any children for which there was a transaction during the specified time for the specified parent.

The problem came up because in processing the result of this query, I went back and asked for current data relating to *all* children (rather than just the ones with relevant transactions, like I should have), and got information even when this query (correctly) told me there was none.

Nothing to see here, move along.

Comment: Perhaps you should tick your answer as accepted in order for people not to stumble over the question only to find out there's nothing to see here.

Comment: Ah, I see, sorry. I knew there was some time limitation, just wasn't aware the wait period was that long.